# Runnable jar not reading file correctly

Tags: java, file-io, intellij-idea, jar

I use IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. When I run my game through the IDE, it works properly. I then export it as a runnable jar, and then it acts as if it can't find the map text file. I looked through the jar with WinRAR and found that the map file is there in the correct place.

This is how I get the lines from a map file:

```
List<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        Game.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/" + file)))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        fileLines.add(line);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.log("Could not find map file " + file + "!", Logger.LogLevel.SEVERE);
}
```

That code is the start of the method `Map.loadmap(String file)`.
This is how I use it:

```
Map map = Map.loadMap("Test.map");
map.init();
```

The jar file works exactly as the program does when running in the IDE when I comment those two lines out. It isn't the `map.init()` that isn't working, but the `Map.loadMap()` (I debugged a little). What could be the problems?

EDIT

Example map file: 
http://pastebin.com/RMHS1Xzb

- First line: name
- Second and third lines: width and height
- Rest: tiles (0 is grass, 1 is wall)

Comment: It's likely got something to do with the classloader. try it with a leading /, `Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + file))))`

Comment: It's also possible that the `resources` directory doesn't actually exist in the Jar.  Use some kind of unzip program to check it's contents

Comment: @stringy05 Now the program can't find the files with that. I used WinRAR and the map file was in the right place in the jar

Comment: where is resources? I should have pointed out - using the leading slash means the path needs to be fully qualified for the directory structure on the classpath. So if `Map` is in the package `/foo/bar` and `mapFile` is in `/foo/bar/resources`, then the relative path to `resources` works, unless you are getting the system classloader (in which case it will have its working dir as the root of the classpath), That's why I think you are getting different behaviour - in the IDE, Intellij is doing something clever with the classloader, whereas in the jar you are getting the JDK system classloader

Comment: @stringy05 I tried that and the program worked in the ide but still not in the jar. `resources` is in the main package, along with the main class

Comment: can you add the file layout and a sample class to the question?

Comment: so you've got /src/main/java/foo/Map.java and /src/main/resources/mapdata.txt, and the jar has /foo/Map.class and /resources/mapdata.txt?

Comment: @stringy05 no the jar and the ide file directories are the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83921/discussion-between-stringy05-and-mcmastery).